# Gradient of log softmax in matrix form

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

Suppose $J(\mathbf{A})$ is defined as follows
$$J=\text{tr}(\log \mathbf{P})$$
$$\mathbf{P}=\frac{e^\mathbf{A}}{\mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}' e^\mathbf{A}}$$

where division, exp and log are taken pointwise, $\mathbf{1}$ is a column vector of ones and $\mathbf{A}$ is square. What's the easiest way of showing that $\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{P}$ is the gradient of $J(\mathbf{A})$?

Comment: Gradient with respect to what?

Comment: Gradient with respect to A, added clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$Just computing, I'd say. We have wrting $P = (p_{ij})$, $A = (a_{ij})$ and $d$ for the dimension
\begin{align*}
  p_{ij} &= \frac{\exp a_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^d \exp a_{kj}}\\
 \log p_{ij} &= a_{ij} - \log \sum_{k=1}^d \exp a_{kj}\\
  J(A) &= 
 \tr\log P\\ &= \tr A - \sum_{l=1}^d \log \sum_{k=1}^d \exp a_{kl}
\end{align*}
So we have 
\begin{align*}
  \partial_{a_{ii}}J(A) &= 1 - \frac 1{\sum_{k=1}^d \exp a_{ki}}\cdot \exp a_{ii}\\
       &= 1 - p_{ii}\\
 \text{and for $i\ne j$:}\\
  \partial_{a_{ij}} &= -\frac 1{\sum_{k=1}^d \exp a_{kj}}\cdot \exp a_{ij}\\
    &= -p_{ij}
\end{align*}
So we have $\nabla J(A) = \mathrm{id} - P(A)$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\oo{{\large\tt11}^T}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let the symbols $(\odot,:)$ denote the Hadamard (aka elementwise)
and Frobenius (aka inner) products, and briefly recall some of their properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
I:A &= \trace{A} \\
A:B &= B:A \\
A\odot B &= B\odot A \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
\LR{A\odot B}:C &= A:\LR{B\odot C} \\
}$$
It is also worth noting the special properties of the all-ones vector $(\o)$
with respect to an elementwise function $(f)$ and an arbitrary vector $(a)$
$$\eqalign{
\o\odot a &= a \quad&\{ {\rm identity\;for\;multiplication} \} \\
a^\ominus\odot a &= \o \quad&\{ a^\ominus\;{\rm denotes\;elementwise\;inverse} \} \\
f(a\o^T) &= f(a)\o^T \quad&\{ {\rm associativity\;with\;function\;args} \} \\
f(\o a^T) &= \o\,f(a^T) \\
\BR{a\o^T}^\ominus &= a^\ominus\o^T \quad&\{ {\rm the\;inverse\;is\;just\;a\;function}  \} \\
}$$
These properties can be extended to the matrix case, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\oo\odot A &= A, \qquad f(\oo A) &= \o\,f(\o^TA) \\
}$$
The differential of an elementwise function is simply
$\:df = f'\odot dx$

For example, if $x$ is a scalar, vector, or matrix
$$\eqalign{
f &= \sin(x) \qiq d\sin(x) = \cos(x) \odot dx \\
}$$

---

With these two products and the all-ones vector we can calculate the requested gradient.
$$\eqalign{
E &= \exp(A) \qiq \c{dE = E\odot dA} \\
P &= E\odot\BR{\oo E}^\ominus \\
J &= I:\log(P) \\
  &= I:\log(E) - I:\log(\oo E) \\
  &= I:A \;-\; \o^T:\log(\o^TE) \\
dJ &= I:dA \;-\; \o^T:\BR{\o^TE}^\ominus\odot(\o^TdE) \\
   &= I:dA \;-\; \BR{\o^TE}^\ominus:(\o^T\c{dE}) \\
   &= I:dA \;-\; \o\BR{\o^TE}^\ominus:\CLR{E\odot dA} \\
   &= I:dA \;-\; E\odot\BR{\oo E}^\ominus:dA \\
   &= \LR{I-P}:dA \\
\grad JA &= \LR{I-P} \\
}$$