# Finding cross entropy gradient in matrix form

Tags: matrix-calculus, machine-learning, differential

I know how to get the cross entropy gradient of a single weight, but that's boring. I want to find the gradient w.r.t the whole weight matrix, but I'm not very confident in my results. I would really appreciate if anyone could check my work here and point me in the right direction. To start define some variables

- $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, an input matrix
- $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$, a weight matrix
- $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, a one-hot target matrix
- $J \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, a matrix of ones

And then some functions

- $P:\mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, where $P(X) = X\beta$
- $S: \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, the softmax function applied row-wise
- $L: \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, take the logarithm of each element,  $L(A)_{i, j} = \log(A_{i,j})$
- $Z: \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, where $Z(A) = Y \odot A$
- $E: \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $E(A) = -tr(JA)$

Then cross entropy loss can be written as

$$\text{cross entropy} = E\Bigg[Z\bigg[L\bigg(S\big(P(X)\big) \bigg) \bigg] \Bigg] $$

Now I'm going to abuse notation and start using $P$ to represent $P(X) = X\beta$, $S$ to represent $S(P(X))$..etc. The chain rule tells us that if the function $F$ is differentiable at point $C$ and the function $G$ is differentiable at point $B = F(C)$, then the composite

$$H(X) = G(F(X)) $$

Is differentiable at $C$, and

$$ DH(C) = \big(DG(B)\big)\big(DF(C) \big)$$

Where $DF(C)$ denotes the Jacobian of $F$ at point $C$. Using this I should be able to write the Jacobian of cross entropy as

$$D\text{cross} = \big(DE(Z)\big)\big(DZ(L) \big)\big(DL(S)\big)\big(DS(P)\big)\big(DP(\beta)\big) $$

Now I just need to take differentials and find the jacobians.

First,
$$d \ vec \ E = -d \ tr(JZ)$$
$$ = -tr(JdZ)$$
$$= -\big(vec J \big)^T d \ vecZ $$
$$\Rightarrow DE(Z) = -\big(vec J \big)^T $$
Second,
$$d vec Z = vec \ d\big(Y \odot L \big) $$
$$= vec \big(Y \odot dL\big) $$
$$ = \text{Diag}\big[vec \ Y \big]d \ vec L $$
$$\Rightarrow DZ(L) =  \text{Diag}\big[vec \ Y \big]$$

Third

$$d \ vec P = vec \ d(X\beta) $$
$$ = vec \big(Xd\beta\big)$$
$$= (I_K \otimes X)d \ vec(\beta)$$
$$\Rightarrow DP(\beta) =  (I_K \otimes X)$$
Now lets assume I have calculated both of $DL(S), DS(P)$. Both of these matrices should be $nk \times nk$. If I combine all of this, I get

$$D\text{cross} = -\big(vec J \big)^T\text{Diag}\big[vec \ Y \big]\big(DL(S)\big)\big(DS(P)\big)(I_K \otimes X) $$

and I tentatively conclude that

$$ \frac{\partial \text{cross}}{\partial \beta}= -\big(vec J \big)^T\text{Diag}\big[vec \ Y \big]\big(DL(S)\big)\big(DS(P)\big)(I_K \otimes X) $$

This has dimension $1\times km$ which is almost what I want....Is this correct? If I use pytorch to calculate $DL(S), DS(P)$, is this derivation of gradient right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\l{\:{\sf cross}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\C{C^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gred#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\c{\p #2}}}
$The Frobenius product (denoted by a colon)
is extremely useful in Matrix Calculus
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_{\c F} \qquad \big({\rm\c{Frobenius}\;norm}\big) \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A &= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Furthermore, it commutes with the Hadamard product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{B\odot C} = \LR{A\odot B}:C 
\;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij}
}$$
For typing convenience, I'll replace $\beta$ with $B$,
and since your $E$ function can be replaced by the Frobenius product,
let's redefine it to be the element-wise exponential
$$\eqalign{
E &= \exp(P) \qiq \c{dE = E\odot dP} \\
}$$
which can be used along with Hadamard division $(\oslash)$
and the all-ones matrix $J$ to construct the row-wise SoftMax function
$$\eqalign{
 S &= E\oslash EJ \quad\qiq S\o = \o \\
\\
dS
  &= \c{dE}\oslash EJ \;-\; E\odot\c{d\LR{EJ}}\oslash EJ\oslash EJ \\
  &= \c{E\odot dP}\oslash EJ \;-\; E\odot\CLR{dE\:J}\oslash EJ\oslash EJ \\
  &= S\odot dP \;-\; S\odot\LR{dE\:J}\oslash EJ \\
}$$
The element-wise logarithm and cross-entropy functions can be differentiated
$$\eqalign{
L &= \log(S) \\
dL &= dS\oslash S \\
  &= dP - \LR{dE\:J}\oslash EJ \\
\\
\l &= -\trace{J(Y\odot L)} \\
 &= -Y:L \\
d\l &= -Y:dL \\
 &= Y:\LR{(dE\:J)\oslash EJ} \;-\; Y:dP \\
 &= \LR{Y\oslash EJ}:\LR{dE\:J} \;-\; Y:dP \\
 &= \GLR{\LR{Y\oslash EJ}J}:{dE} \;-\; Y:dP \\
 &= \g{Q}:\c{dE} \;-\; Y:dP \\
 &= Q:\CLR{E\odot dP} \;-\; Y:dP \\
 &= \LR{E\odot Q}:dP \;-\; Y:dP \\
 &= \LR{E\odot Q-Y}:dP \\
}$$
Finally, substituting $P=XB\:$ yields the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= \LR{E\odot Q-Y}:(X\:dB) \\
  &= X^T\LR{E\odot Q-Y}:{dB} \\
\grad{\l}{B} &= X^T\LR{E\odot Q-Y} \\
 &= X^T\LR{E\odot\LR{\LR{Y\oslash EJ}J}\;-\;Y} \\
}$$
Notice that this gradient has the same dimensions as the matrix $B,\,$
which are the same as the dimensions of the product $X^TY$

If the one-hot matrix is defined such that $Y\o=\o,\:$ then the
gradient expression simplifies to
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\l}{B} &= X^T\LR{S-Y} \\
}$$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247874) is a related question.

Comment: Are there any textbooks/resources you recommend for learning matrix calculus?

Comment: Exploring posts on this site carrying the _Matrix Calculus_ tag would be a good start, and it's free (I added it to your post, just click on it). Beyond that, the standard text is probably Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_, although personally I prefer Hjorungnes's _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_